# flexbox - wrapping at smaller dimensions

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a long box with 4 inner side by side boxes(divs).  Each inner div is 150px x 150px.  Well, 150px plus/minus the borders I guess.  At full desktop width I have the following css applied:

```
.stock-info {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1.1vw);
  border-left: 1px solid #777777;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
}

.stock-info .box {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
}
```

[image]

Now when the width of the window shrinks, I want the the boxes to stay the same height and width.  Maybe I need to be making it `flex-basis: 150px;` instead of `flex:1`.  And then when the screen gets too small to handle all 4 boxes I want it to drop to 2x2 and stay there all the way down.  I never want a box to be alone on a row.

This is what I've tried for the smaller dimensions.  It switches to a single column and the borders get hosed up.  I'm doing borders like that based off another suggestion I found somewhere online to avoid the double inner borders.  Maybe there is a better way to do that as well.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .stock-info {
    width: 300px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .stock-info .box {
    flex-basis: 150px;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boxes are stacking because your borders are adding width to your boxes.

You can add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to your `.box` class so that the widths are applied *inward* instead of *outward*.

> **Note:** For new web sites, you may wish to begin with `box-sizing` set to `border-box`. This makes dealing with the sizes of elements much easier, and generally eliminates a number of pitfalls you can stumble on while laying out your content.

```css
.stock-info {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1.1vw);
  border-left: 1px solid #777777;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
}

.stock-info .box {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .stock-info {
    width: 300px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .stock-info .box {
    flex-basis: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stock-info">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup that was it.  Also, turned out my border logic was screwing things up.  I switched it to just a single border around every `.box` and then added in a margin-left of -1px and margin-bottom of -1px and seemed to fix all my issues!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think [Tyler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122760/636077) is the better solution.

Your border will be added to your box size, so they're 151px, not 150. You could set a `max-width: calc(50% - 1px)` to account for the border, like so:

```css
.stock-info {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1.1vw);
  border-left: 1px solid #777777;
  border-top: 1px solid #777777;
}

.stock-info .box {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 150px;
  border-right: 1px solid #777777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
}

.stock-info {
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
  
 .stock-info .box {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  max-width: calc(50% - 1px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="stock-info">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having this issue is that your boxes are all actually larger than you think they are. You're assuming that 150px is the size of the entire box, but that's not true - it's actually 150px **plus the size of the borders** (and the padding, if you had any.) This is because you're using the default `box-sizing` value, `box-sizing: content-box;`

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) is a good read to explain box-sizing -- but you can set it to behave in a more intuitive way by putting this at the top of all your CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

That way all elements of `width: 150px;` will be 150px total.

Finally ... it still won't work. Why? Because you've defined your outer box to be 300px wide now at small screen sizes, *including* the borders. This technically only leaves 299px of inner width once you factor in the borders, which is not enough to fit your 2x150px children.

I would suggest using a `flex-basis: 50%;` instead, which should cause the box to take up 50% of the available width, which pretty much what you're trying to do anyway.